# HttpUtility.UrlDecode turns %2b into space, but I need it to be '+'

Tags: html, http

I'm using HttpUtility.UrlEncode to turn parameter value which concluds '+' to safe string deliverd among pages, so it turns '+' into %2b, but when I use Decode method it give me back a space. Why?

Comment: When `%2b` gets decoded, you get a space character?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Decoding `%2b` would give you back a `+`, but decoding a `+` would give you back a space.

So, most likely your string is decoded twice. If you are reading it from the `Request.Querystring` collection, then it's already decoded, so you shouldn't decode it again.

Comment: Exactly!, I use request.querystring.

Answer (score 0):

Weird, the following prints `+` on my console (as expected):

```
Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("+")));
```