# HttpUtility.UrlDecode is replacing + with space

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, urldecode, system.web

I am trying to decode a Microsoft Identity Register Email token with `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` in Asp.net WebApi controller. I observed that this method is replacing `+` characters with `space`.

e.g

`HttpUtility.UrlDecode("TWi7P9ekNTBB6cZuoNAzQbN8jFKvDcqFshzKpHpP8VbZmsx8HvzwMIqRwDVV34YhG6xe/FCjTyiaX8p+lwYdjyk/oJ/+eFKOOez0/tiDyLCFCT62UxY5edvZbqFz8bVSkpFGWSDSn3JjLQBsCVe3WbyqJ40UGzB+TGV+SRbrth69fxWI6YrFmWoyK7XBtpWs")`

Returns 
`TWi7P9ekNTBB6cZuoNAzQbN8jFKvDcqFshzKpHpP8VbZmsx8HvzwMIqRwDVV34YhG6xe/FCjTyiaX8p lwYdjyk/oJ/ eFKOOez0/tiDyLCFCT62UxY5edvZbqFz8bVSkpFGWSDSn3JjLQBsCVe3WbyqJ40UGzB TGV SRbrth69fxWI6YrFmWoyK7XBtpWs`

If you observe, the return token has spaces in between. Those spaces were formed because of `+` signs in the original token.

I am getting the token from browser as part of `api route :  /api/{token}/validate`.

Is there anyway i can decode microsoft identity generated token without replacing `+` signs.

Comment: The token does not look URL encoded to me. If it was URL encoded the slashes would probably be percent-encoded. Are you sure it's not already decoded?

Comment: in addition to what @Matti said, `String.Replace("+", "%2B")`

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6753901/21567)?

Comment: You should encode first, then the '+' will become '%20', otherwise the plus is replaced as a space. This is standard HTTP.